# How to create a dictionary which will have common keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.7, python-3.8

I am trying to create a **Dictionary** using **keys** and **Values**

```
keys = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9]
```

and values.

```
values = ['a', 'b' , 'c' ,'d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
```

using **zip** function or using a for loop.

```
dict1 = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(dict1)
```

The output is.

```
{1: 'g', 2: 'i', 3: 'j', 4: 'l', 5: 'm', 6: 'n', 7: 'p', 8: 'q', 9: 'r'}
```

But the dict  ignores the values for common keys. Like it ignores 1: 'a' and many more.

**Please tell me a way to deal with it.**

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What do you think you are going to do with a `dict` if you could get one just as you like?

Comment: Please read up on what a `dict` is  - as an analogy - an array cannot have repeated "indexes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dict cannot have multiple identical keys.
But you can have multiple identical values.

For example:

```py
a = {
    1: "a",
    1: "b"
}
print(a)  # {1: 'b'}
b = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1
}
print(b)  # {'a': 1, 'b': 1}
```

#### Why

Keys must be unique, because you access values with `my_dict[key]`. If `my_dict[key]` give multiple values, which one do you choose ?

#### Alternative

You can store multiple values for a key in a list:

```py
keys = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9]
values = ['a', 'b' , 'c' ,'d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']

dict1 = dict()
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    if key in dict1:
        dict1[key].append(value)
    else:
        dict1[key] = [value]

print(dict1)
# {1: ['a', 'f', 'g'], 2: ['b', 'h', 'i'], 3: ['c', 'j'], 4: ['d', 'k', 'l'], 5: ['e']}
```

#### With collections.defaultdict

```py
from collections import defaultdict

keys = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9]
values = ['a', 'b' , 'c' ,'d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']

dict1 = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    dict1[key].append(value)

print(dict(dict1))
# {1: ['a', 'f', 'g'], 2: ['b', 'h', 'i'], 3: ['c', 'j'], 4: ['d', 'k', 'l'], 5: ['e']}
```

Comment: You can also use `dict1.setdefault(key, []).append(value)` :)

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM you can edit my answer to add your suggestion if you want

Answer (score 1):

This should ideally be a comment on Dorian's answer above. However, I don't have enough reputation points to comment. Just wanted to add that, I prefer to use defaultdict() instead of dict() to avoid the step of having to check if the key is already in use.

```
from collections import defaultdict 

keys = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9]
values = ['a', 'b' , 'c' ,'d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']

dict1 = defaultdict(lambda:[])
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    dict1[key].append(value)
    
print(dict1)
# {1: ['a', 'f', 'g'], 2: ['b', 'h', 'i'], 3: ['c', 'j'], 4: ['d', 'k', 'l'], 5: ['e']}
```

If you want to learn more about defaultdict() usage, here is a nice reference https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/using-defaultdict-python

Comment: See my edit 20 minutes ago :) 
Instead of `defaultdict(lambda:[])`, you should use `defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: oops, sorry about that. when I started editing my answer, I didn't see the edit.